# What is a person called if they study poems but do not write them?

Tags: word-usage, poetry, literary-english

I am doing a research paper for Robert Frost and Emily Dickinson. I do not know the term to use if I'm trying to talk about someone who studied the poems they made before they died. Can anyone help me find a term closest to this or a definition to help me?

Comment: One could speak of someone as a student of Frost or Dickinson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Literary critic.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_criticism)

A term for poetic studies specifically does not exist to the best of my knowledge.